# Prescribing an induced metric

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curvature

We know that, if we have a surface $z=f(x,y)$ with Euclidean space being ambient manifold, the induced metric is as follows (in matrix form):
$$g=\begin{bmatrix}
1+\left ( \frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial x} \right )^2 & \frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial y} & \\\ 
\frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial y} & 1+\left ( \frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial y} \right )^2 & 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, consider a problem of prescribing an induced metric, i.e. assume we have a metric

$$h=\begin{bmatrix}
a(x,y) & b(x,y)\\\ 
b(x,y) & c(x,y)
\end{bmatrix}$$

The question is, when metric $h$ is an induced metric, i.e. when there exist a surface $z=f(x,y)$ for which an induced metric is $h$?

An example would be a metric
$$h=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\\ 
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

for which there exist a surface $z=-(x+y)$ with an induced metric being
$$g=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\\ 
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$

An obvious obstruction is that the following identity has to be satisfied by the givien metric:
$$a(x,y)c(x,y)-a(x,y)-c(x,y)+1=b^2(x,y).$$
This identity follows from requirement that 
$$\frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial y}=b(x,y).$$

Ths problem occured when toying with several examples of positive definite Hessians (with minus sign), i.e. when (minus) Hessian for some other surface $z=\phi(x,y)$ is positive definite. For example, if $z=-(x^2+xy+y^2)$, then the minus Hessian is
$$h=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1\\\ 
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix can be taken as a first fundamental form of the surface $z=-(x+y)$, which has a zero Gaussian curvature. It seems that often when negative Hessian is taken as a first fundamental form, Gaussian curvature (for a surface with induced metric being equal to this negative Hessian) is equal to zero. I'm not claiming that this is a general phenomena, it's just an interesting observation (it is important from the point of view of optimization as Hessian often play a significant role there).

I looked for litereture on "prescribed metric" problem, but found none. Probably I wasn't looking in the right place. **A link to a paper, of a monograph considering this problem would be appreciated**.

I'm familiar with the problem of prescribed curvature. Probably one possible way would be to look for prescribed Ricci curvature tensor problem. But at this stage I think it would be an overkill. And maybe the class of possible solutions (taking into consideration the obstructions) is way too small and simple to be of value: it looks like negative Hessians for quadratic surfaces might a class of solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $b\ne0$.

Then you know $\alpha=\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\beta=\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ up to sign. 
You should check $$\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}.$$ 
If this is true you can restore $f$ by integrating.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I know this. This is a very easy part. But there is additional condition on the metric that we want to prescribe. Namely, $\alpha\beta = b$.

Comment: @Tomas: Once you know a, b, and c you  know α and β up to sign. In particular αβ=b.

Comment: So, $\alpha = \pm \sqrt{(a-1)}$, and $\beta = \pm \sqrt{(c-1)}$. Then there is a condition that $\alpha \beta = \sqrt{(a-1)(c-1)}=b$. In other words, if $ac-a-c+1=b^2$, then I can restore the surface $z=f(x,y)$. If this condition is not satisfied, then a given matrix $h$ there is no surface (at least not with Euclidean space as ambiant manifold) with $h$ as an induced metric

Comment: @Tomas, almost right --- in addition you need to check that $\tfrac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y}=\tfrac{\partial \beta}{\partial x}$ and if yes then yes.